# Can a Chrome packaged app and a Chrome extension share local data?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

From what I gather, Chrome apps and Chrome extensions are just two different ways of viewing some basic html/js/css files that have access to certain Chrome APIs.  What I'd like to know is - can you share data between them?  For example, can I do `localStorage.setItem('name', 'john');` in a Chrome app, and have `localStorage.getItem('name');` return `john` in an extension?  If so, how do I link the app and the extension so that this is possible?

Comment: Try it, and report back.

Comment: Check out [cross-extension message passing](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/messaging.html#external).